Error in using mlogit function: "replacement has 8 rows, data has 9"
I am trying to estimate a simple multinomial logit model. The utility of a product is given by:
U_{ij}=\beta⋅price_{ij}​+fixed_effect_j​+ϵ_{ij}.
I have data which contains the choices made by individuals i, across products j. (Each product may not be sampled on each occasion, and the number of products sampled may vary. I observe the sampled products and the product which is selected amongst the sampled products). My aim is to estimate \beta and the fixed_effects for each product.
I believe I can use the following code for this:
library(mlogit)
# Example data (already in long format)
temp <- data.table(
  session_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  object_id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  chosen = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  price = c(10, 20, 30, 25, 20, 15, 30, 25, 10)
)

# Ensure consistent data types
temp[, session_id := as.integer(session_id)]
temp[, object_id := as.integer(object_id)]
temp[, chosen := as.integer(chosen)]
temp[, price := as.numeric(price)]

# Print the data to verify
print("Original data:")
print(temp)

# Check the dimensions
print("Dimensions of temp:")
print(dim(temp))

# Fit the multinomial logit model using mlogit
formula <- chosen ~ 0 | object_id + price
model <- mlogit(formula, data = temp, choice = "chosen", shape = "long", alt.var = "object_id", id.var = "session_id")


but I get the error:

model <- mlogit(formula, data = temp, choice = "chosen", shape = "long", alt.var = "object_id", id.var = "session_id")

Error in $<-.data.frame(x, name, value) :
replacement has 8 rows, data has 9
I do not know what is causing this, nor does ChatGPT. Please help!

You should specify the packages you are using in your question.

@LMc The mlogit package. Editted.

Did you notice that mlogit package was maintained last time in 2020? Try using nnet::multinom(chosen ~ price + factor(object_id), data=temp) or VGAM::vglm(chosen ~ price + factor(object_id), family=multinomial(), data=temp) to calculate multinomial models.

@jay.sf Thanks! I did not know that. The two models are not equivalent though? multinom(chosen ~ price + factor(object_id) is a log-linear model, whereas mlogit is a logit model?

@user20380762 Not sure, currently not working much with multinomial models. Try VGAM, remember it was cool. nnet involved some machine learning stuff, while vglm and mlogit yielded similar results. Good luck!
